# Reverse proxy to subpath (uptime kuma status page)

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I am using uptime kuma behind a reverse proxy. This is my configuration and it works

```
server  {
    listen       80;
    listen  [::]:80;

    server_name    kuma.my-domain.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass         $uptime_kuma_path;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade \$http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header   Host \$host;
        proxy_ssl_name \$host;
        proxy_ssl_server_name on;
        proxy_ssl_verify off;
        proxy_ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
    }
}
```

I wanted to make it so `status.my-domain.com` will point to `kuma.my-domain.com/status/my-app`. This is the configuration I tried:

```
server  {
    listen       80;
    listen  [::]:80;

    server_name    status.my-domain.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass         $uptime_kuma_path/status/my-app;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade \$http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header   Host \$host;
        proxy_ssl_name \$host;
        proxy_ssl_server_name on;
        proxy_ssl_verify off;
        proxy_ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
    }
}
```

After applying this, `status.my-domain.com` is a blank page and after opening dev tools I can see that I get response "Javascript is not enabled on this browser". What am I doing wrong?